# Transform table into 2 columns

Tags: linux, bash, awk

How do i transform table like this:

```
1   0.75    1   0.38
2   0.80    2   0.18
```

to something like:

```
1   0.75
2   0.80
1   0.38
2   0.18
```

The coloumn separated by a tab character or comma.

I want to do it in linux bash, with any number of colounm and rows. I tried to do it with awk but didn't find the right way.

Thanks

Comment: Are your columns separated by a tab character or by multiple spaces?

Comment: The coloumn separated by a tab character or comma.

Comment: What do you mean "any number of columns"? Show another example please.

Comment: Define `something like` or just show **the** output you want. Does `The coloumn separated by a tab character or comma.` mean that within 1 file there can be tabs or commas between fields, or there's just 1 or the other within any given file or something else. Does a solution need to work for both together or either one or...? Just be clear and precise, don't leave it up to us to guess at what you want.

Comment: `tried to do it with awk` please add that attempt to question.. otherwise question comes across as asking for free coding service..

Answer (score 1):

Here is one in awk:

```
$ awk '
BEGIN{ FS=OFS="\t" }                                        # tab-delimited
NR==1{ nf=NF }                                              # get field count 
{
    for(i=1;i<nf;i+=2)                                      # iterate every other field
        if(i==1)                                            # print first 2 fields
            print $1,$2
        else                                                # buffer others
            b[i]=b[i] sprintf("%s" OFS "%s" ORS,$i,$(i+1))
}
END {                                                       # in the end
    for(i=3;i<nf;i+=2)                                      # iterate buffers
        printf "%s",b[i]                                    # and output
}' file
1       0.75
2       0.80
1       0.38
2       0.18
```

**Edit**: An awk-sort-cut hybrid:

```
$ awk '                   # awk to add field number to output
BEGIN { FS=OFS="\t" }     # tab-delimiter
{
    for(i=1;i<NF;i+=2)    # iterate fields
        print i,$i,$(i+1) # print field number and data fields
}' file |
sort -s -t $'\t' -k1n |   # sort on the first field only
cut -f 2-
1       0.75
2       0.80
1       0.38
2       0.18
```

Answer (score 1):

Using cut, with comma delimiters:

```
cut -d, -f1-2 input > output && cut -d, -f3-4 input >> output
```

input:

```
1,0.75,1,0.38
2,0.80,2,0.18
```

output:

```
1,0.75
2,0.80
1,0.38
2,0.18
```

For tab delimited file use: `cut -d$'\t' ...`

This is two pass but uses constant memory. Easy to extend to any number of columns.

If you don't mind the order you can just do:

```
sed 's/\([^,]*,[^,]*\),/\1\n/' input
```

Answer (score 0):

Following `xargs` and `awk` combination may help you on same too(considering that your actual Input_file is same as shown samples).

```
xargs -n2 < Input_file | awk '{a[FNR]=$0} END{for(i=1;i<=FNR;i+=2){print a[i]};for(i=2;i<=FNR;i+=2){print a[i]}}'
```

Answer (score 0):

Expanding the example a bit:

```
$ cat file
1   0.75    1   0.38    1   a
2   0.80    2   0.18    2   b
3   0.80    3   0.18    3   c
```

Then

```
$ # count the number of rows
$ n=$(wc -l < file)

$ # the first awk and pr will transpose the input,
$ # then another awk to print in a single column
$ awk -v OFS='\t' '{for (i=1; i<NF; i+=2) print $i, $(i+1) }' file |
  pr -${n}t |
  awk -v OFS='\t' '{for (i=1; i<NF; i+=2) print $i, $(i+1) }'
```

```
1   0.75
2   0.80
3   0.80
1   0.38
2   0.18
3   0.18
1   a
2   b
3   c
```

Answer (score 0):

Using `sed` and the shell which support brace-expansion and steps (I know zsh and bash):

```
sed '-es/,/\n/'{7..2..2} infile
```

Please note that range should be always `max` first in `{max#..min#..step#}`. Replace `max` with very big number if you don't know how many columns do you have in your file.

You can also specify which positions range should replace by `{x,y,z}` format, where numbers should be `x>y>z`.

Don't use `{x,x}` (same number) as it will cause a problem and will replace position `x` again and again (BTW for this there is `s/,/\n/X` alternative where `X` is position number).

for the given below input:

```
1,0.75,1,0.38,1,0.18,4,0.17
2,0.80,2,0.18,2,0.03,3,3.16
```

The output is:

```
1,0.75
1,0.38
1,0.18
4,0.17
2,0.80
2,0.18
2,0.03
3,3.16
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$ awk '
    BEGIN { FS=OFS="\t" }
    { for (i=1;i<=NF;i++) a[i,NR]=$i }
    END {for (i=1;i<=NF;i+=2) for (j=1;j<=NR;j++) print a[i,j], a[i+1,j]}
' file
1       0.75
2       0.80
1       0.38
2       0.18
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$ cat file | tee >(cut -f1-2) >(cut -f3-4) >/dev/null
```

`tee` to two cut processes and throw away the real output.
will work as is if the columns are tab delimited, otherwise you need to set the delimiter for the `cut` command.